# Methods copied from the Facebook login manual display a "not applicable" error

Tags: android, facebook

This program shows error-"The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, MainFragment)" at .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).MainFragment is a class that extends Fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
         private MainFragment mainFragment;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
                mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
                .commit();
            } else {
                // Or set the fragment from restored state info
                mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

    }
```

MainFragment.java

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: check your imports to be sure that all are either from the support libraries or the framework

Comment: @blackbelt Now I have posted imports also

Comment: As blackfizz mentioned, be careful to use the classes from the same package. If you support lower versions than 3.0 then always use support.v4.*. If you go 3.0 and up just use the android.app package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have used the native `Fragment` for your `MainFragment` and not the support `Fragment`. Because you are using the `SupportFragmentManager` and this needs the support version of the `Fragment`.

Replace in your `MainFragment` the import

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: It's clear, he is using support fragment activity with basic fragments.